# Help on derivative of trigonometric functions

Tags: functions, trigonometry, derivatives, solution-verification

I have simple problem in derivative of trigonometric functions, can anyone show me the way to calculate the derivative of following function?

$$y = \sin^2 x (\cos x + \sin x)$$

I think the answer should be:

$$y' = (2 \sin x \cos x)(\cos x + \sin x) + (-\sin x + \cos x)(\sin^2 x)$$

Is the above answer correct?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You should apply the chain rule to differentiate $\sin^2 x$.

Comment: It's incorrect. What's the derivative of $x\mapsto (\sin(x))^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. 
$$(\sin^2 x)^\prime\not=2\sin x.$$
$$(\sin^2 x)^\prime=2\sin x\cdot (\sin x)^\prime=2\sin x\cos x.$$

The other parts are fine.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d\{\sin^2x(\cos x+\sin x)\}}{dx}=(\cos x+\sin x)\frac{d(\sin^2x)}{dx}+\sin^2x\frac{d(\cos x+\sin x)}{dx}$$

$$=(\cos x+\sin x)\cdot\frac{d(\sin^2x)}{d(\sin x)}\cdot\frac{d(\sin x)}{dx}+\sin^2x(-\cos x+\cos x)$$

$$=\cdots$$

Reference : [Product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule)  and [Chain Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)